# Passing HTML to Node.js from PHP

Tags: php, node.js, command-line-interface

I have an application mostly written in `PHP`, but there is a `npm` package that has functionality that I need to incorporate into my application. I ***must*** pass a string of `HTML` into the `Node.js` application but am having issues in getting things correct. I'm using:

```
exec('node '.$rootPath.'node/app.js '.$imageId.' email '.escapeshellcmd($emailString).' 2>&1', $output, $retVar);
```

to send the data to my `Node.js` application, but I'm unsure as to how to decode it once it gets there and needs to be processed via `JavaScript`. Is there a way to unescape `escapeshellcmd()` in JavaScript? Or is there a different way I should pass these long strings of `HTML` over the command-line?

EDIT: Here is the exact method I'm using to pass my info to Node.js:

```
    try{
        $emailString = escapeshellcmd($decoded);
        //`node $rootPath'node/app.js' $imageId email $emailString 2>&1`;
        exec('node '.$rootPath.'node/app.js '.$imageId.' email "'.$emailString.'" 2>&1', $output, $retVar);
        print_r($output);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    }
```

And here is app.js:

```
process.argv.forEach(function(value, index, array){
     if(index == 2){
        id = value;
     }
     if(index == 3){
        type = value;
    }
    if(index == 4){
        visual = value;
    }
});
console.log('******* FROM NODE********');
console.log(visual);
```

It seems like only the first line is getting passed or collected and printed back, and it looks like it's still encoded (unless the console is re-encoding when printing). Also I'm not sure why it seems to be appending values instead of overwriting them:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ******* FROM NODE********
\<head\>\<style type=text/css\>body \{padding:0\; margin:0\; text-align:center\;.tbl1 \{background-color:\#a53f0f\; color:\#fff\; text-align:center\; font-size:\<body data-gramm=true data-gramm_editor=true data-gramm_id=ccdbd45c-b0bf-4691-9\<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style=background-color:
)

Array
(
    [0] => ******* FROM NODE********
\<head\>\<style type=text/css\>body \{padding:0\; margin:0\; text-align:center\;.tbl1 \{background-color:\#a53f0f\; color:\#fff\; text-align:center\; font-size:\<body data-gramm=true data-gramm_editor=true data-gramm_id=ccdbd45c-b0bf-4691-9\<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style=background-color:
    [2] => ******* FROM NODE********
\<html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml xmlns:v=urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml         \<meta name=viewport content=width=device-width,e\>
)
```

Comment: Why are you using `2>&1`. No need to discard the output.

Comment: @srimaln91 It's not discarded but `stderr` is redirected to `stdout` - same result as viewed in the terminal. Discard would be `2>/dev/null`

Comment: @srimaln91 However, I prefer handling all standard streams separately using `proc_open`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Please see the edit.

Comment: At first +1 upvote for the [mcve]. Another question, independently from the issue: Do you really need to pass the mail body by argument which might become a very large text? The common way to process text data is to act as filter between STDIN and STDOUT streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Quasimodo's clone's answer does work, his comment on the question made me think about passing the large strings of HTML. I have instead opted to write the html to file and reference with the id.

Answer (score 1):

Note: You should use streams over arguments for data to be processed. This is the common way as commands work in the Unix world.

In your code you try to use `escapeshellcmd` to escape double quote `"` an encapsulated argument string. This does not work. There is an `escapeshellarg` PHP function as well. It will encapsulate the string in single quotes `'` and escape characters that are even in single quoted strings treated in a special way by the shell.

Assuming `$decoded` is something like

```
$decoded = '<body lang="en">very boring message</body>';
```

then you do not enclose it into quotes yourself. Let `escapeshellarg` do the trick.

```
$emailString   = escapeshellarg($decoded);
$imageIdString = escapeshellarg($imageId);
exec("node app.js {$imageIdString} email {$emailString} 2>&1", $output, $retVar);
```

---

As mentioned above, you really should consider to work on streams instead of arguments. The advantage is that the data can grow to an arbitrary size. Further more `proc_open` handles `STDOUT` and `STDERR` separately. This can be done like that:

```
try
{
  if($handle = proc_open("node app.js {$imageId} email";, [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']], $streams))
  {
    [$stdin, $stdout, $stderr] = $streams;

    fwrite($stdin, $decoded);
    fclose($stdin);

    $output = stream_get_contents($stdout);
    fclose($stdout);

    $error  = stream_get_contents($stderr);
    fclose($stderr);

    proc_close($handle);
  }

  echo 'OUTPUT:', PHP_EOL, $output, PHP_EOL;
  echo 'ERRORS:', PHP_EOL, $error, PHP_EOL;

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is an example node.js script handling both, data by arg as well as by stdin:

```
(() =>
{
  'use strict';

  console.log('******* FROM NODE********');

  const
    getStdin = require('get-stdin');

  var id, type, visual;
  [,, id, type, visual] = process.argv;


  // if 4th command line argument is present, use that
  if(undefined !== visual)
    processData(visual);

  // otherwise read data from stdin stream
  else
    getStdin().then(visual =>
    {
      processData(visual);
    });


  function processData(data)
  {
    console.log('id'  , id  );
    console.log('type', type);


    console.log('STDIN:', data);
    console.error('no errors');

    console.log('******* DONE *******');
  }

})();
```